# Execute .exe and parameters through C# and cmd command

Tags: c#

Although there are some explanations regarding my problem, I can't solve the following cmd command issue. My goal is to start an .exe with some parameters through C#, which has to manipulate more than one file in a row. Even if I wait until the process has finished, it does not end. Without waiting for the end (Process.WaitForExit()), it looks like the different commands are terminating each other without execution. How can I achieve, with the following method, execution of each .exe file I want to?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"\c Path_of_the_exe " + Path_of_the_file;

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
   exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it read `/c` instead of `\c`?

Comment: Why bother using CMD to launch the app when you could just call the executable directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any reason why you would need to use cmd.exe to launch an exe.  You can just launch your exe directly:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.FileName = Path_of_the_exe;
startInfo.Arguments = Path_of_the_file;

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
   exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Launching cmd.exe like you are may explain the behaviour you are experiencing

Comment: Thanks! It works. I did not know that i can use parameters without opening the cmd.exe explicitly.

Comment: I also cannot imagine a reason for launching "cmd", but those reasons seem to exists, e. g. [see how Mads does](https://github.com/madskristensen/ImageOptimizer/blob/master/src/Compressor.cs) it in his Image Optimizer VS extension. @madskvistkristensen